# Java, unzip folder with German characters in filenames

Tags: java, utf-8, unzip

I'm trying to unzip folder that contains German characters in it, for example Aufhänge .
I know that in Java 7, it is using utf-8 by default, and i think "ä" is one of the utf-8 characters.
Here is my code snippet

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(ZIP_PATH), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    ZipEntry zipEntry;
    while ((zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        System.out.println(zipEntry.getName());
    }
}
```

This is an error that I get: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED

It works with Charset.forName("Cp437"), but it doesn't work with StandardCharsets.UTF_8

Comment: Can you please share the ZIP file if it does not contain any personal information

Comment: its very easy to reproduce, just create text file with name Aufhänge and zip it

Comment: I had tried with it but I am not getting an error

Comment: I am usign JAVA8 for compilation

Comment: I'm using Java 8 too. Maybe problem can be in Operating System. I'm using windows 10. I think on linux filenames are encoded in different way.

Comment: I am also using windows 10

Comment: We have reproduced this problem with Java 8 and 7zip when there were many files with special characters in the zip, not just 1 file.

Answer (score 16):

You don't mention your operating system, nor how you created the zip file, but I managed to recreate your problem anyway, using **7-Zip** on Windows 10:

- Create a simple text file with some trivial content (e.g. nothing but the three characters "abc").
- Save the file as **D:\Temp\Aufhänge.txt**. Note the umlaut in the file name.
- Locate that file in Windows File Explorer.
- Select the file and right click. From the context menu select **7-Zip > Add to "Aufhänge.zip"** to create **Aufhänge.zip**.

Then, in NetBeans run the following code to unzip the file you just created:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class GermanZip {

    static String ZIP_PATH = "D:\\Temp\\Aufhänge.zip";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(ZIP_PATH), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        ZipEntry zipEntry;
        while ((zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            System.out.println(zipEntry.getName());
        }
    }

}
```

As you pointed out, the code throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED` when executing this statement: `zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null`.

The problem arises because by default **7-Zip** encodes the names of the files within the zip file using Cp437, as noted in [this comment from 7-Zip](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/82ae0f9c/#dcf2):

> **Default encoding is OEM (DOS) encoding**. It's for compatibility with
>   old zip software.

That's why the unzip works when using `Charset.forName("Cp437")` instead of `Charset.forName("UTF-8")`.

If you want to unzip using `Charset.forName("UTF-8")` then you have to force **7-Zip** to encode the filenames within the zip in UTF-8. To do this specify the **cu** parameter when running **7-Zip**, as noted in the linked comment:

- In Windows File Explorer select the file and right click.
- From the context menu select **7-Zip > Add to Archive..."**.
- In the **Add to Archive** dialog specify **cu** in the **Parameters** field:

  [image: AddToArchive]
- Having stored the zipped filenames in UTF-8 format, you can then replace `Charset.forName("Cp437")` with `Charset.forName("UTF-8")` in your code, and no exception will be thrown when unzipping.

This answer is specific to Windows 10 and 7-Zip, but the general principle should apply in any environment: if specifying an encoding of UTF-8 for your `ZipInputStream` be certain that the filenames within the zip file really are encoded using UTF-8. You can easily verify this by opening the zip file in a binary editor and searching for the names of the zipped files.

---

**Update based on OP's comment/question below:**

- Unfortunately the [.ZIP File Format Specification](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) does not currently provide a way to store the encoding used for zipped file names apart from one exception, as described in "APPENDIX D - Language Encoding (EFS)":

  > D.2 If general purpose bit 11 is unset, the file name and comment
  >   SHOULD conform  to the original ZIP character encoding.  **If general
  >   purpose bit 11 is set, the  filename and comment MUST support The
  >   Unicode Standard, Version 4.1.0 or  greater using the character
  >   encoding form defined by the UTF-8 storage  specification.**  The
  >   Unicode Standard is published by the The Unicode Consortium
  >   (www.unicode.org).  UTF-8 encoded data stored within ZIP files  is
  >   expected to not include a byte order mark (BOM).
- So in your code, for each zipped file, first check whether bit 11 of the **general purpose bit flag** is set. If it is then you can be certain that the name of that zipped fie is encoded using **UTF-8**. Otherwise the encoding is whatever was used when the zipped file was created. That is **Cp437** by default on Windows, but if you are running on Windows and processing a zip file created on Linux I don't think there is an easy way of determining the encoding(s) used.
- Unfortunately [ZipEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html) does not provide a method to access the **general purpose bit flag** field of a zipped file, so you would need to process the zip file at the byte level to do that.
- To add a further complication, "encoding" in this context relates to the encoding used for each zipped filename rather than for the zip file itself. One zipped file name could be encoded in **UTF-8**, another zipped file name could have been added using **Cp437**, etc.

Comment: Thank you, however, I'm writing client for general public, which means some zips will be encoded with Cp437 and some with other encodings. Should I just try one encoding, if wrong, catch exception and then try another one and so on? there is no better way?

Comment: @LukaGorgadze I've updated my answer. If the zip file was created on Windows then assume **UTF-8** if bit 11 of the **general purpose bit flag** is set, as described in my update. Otherwise assume **Cp437**, but also catch any `IllegalArgumentException`, and research the encoding used to create that zipped file. Then enhance your code to cater for other encodings as needed. See [How can I correctly decompress a ZIP archive of files with Hebrew names?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251969/how-can-i-correctly-decompress-a-zip-archive-of-files-with-hebrew-names) for more information.